# Searchview not showing in Toolbar

Tags: android, menu, searchview

I have actually a problem with my Searchview on the Support AppCompat v7 lib 24.0.0.

The SearchView is not shown up no text and input text (look screenshot)

[image]

The searchquery work perfect.

Thats my menu

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <item
        android:title="@string/search"
        android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_search_24dp"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"
        app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"/>
</menu>
```

And here my onCreateOptionsMenu;

```
menu.clear();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_search, menu);
        MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
        searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchItem);
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                //Perform the final search

                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                //Text has changed, apply filtering?

                return false;
            }
        });
```

I hope someone can help me. :)

Sebastian

Comment: Why do you call menu.clear()? It should not be the problem because you are inflating it after again, but give it a try without the menu.clear()?

Comment: because it show me all items double

Comment: Thats strange, can you show more of your Fragment?

Comment: yes it show me two search icons and when i click one it show me the blank toolbar what you see in the screenshot and the three point for more

Comment: to be honest, i'm sick of such bugs in each support lib release

Answer (score 21, accepted):

i have this problem too, i've changed Toolbar height to absolute value instead of wrap_content and problem solved. i don't know why but i think this issue is related to CoordinatorLayout and height of toolbar, something breaks the SearchView height. if i use LinearLayout instead of CoordinatorLayout and AppBarLayout it works.

menu.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_search_white_24dp"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="@string/action_search"
        app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
        app:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView" />
</menu>
```

layout.xml

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/toolbar_height"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/toolbar_top_padding"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:title="@string/drawer_item_publisher_customization"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
            app:tabGravity="fill"
            style="@style/DefaultTabLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

toolbar_height value:

```
<dimen name="toolbar_height">75dp</dimen>
```

Before absolute height value (layout_height:"wrap_content"):
[image: Before absolute height value]

After absolute height value (layout_height:"75dp"):
[image: After absolute height value]

Comment: Thanks that was the problem :D

Comment: It would be better if you skip the custom dimen and set the toolbar height to: android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"

Comment: Why not use `?android:attr/actionBarSize`?

Comment: @NeonWarge `?android:attr/actionBarSize` is defined as `wrap_content`, not as a fixed value.

Comment: @SqueezyMo ?android:attr/actionBarSize worked for me ! Cleaner solution !

Answer (score 7):

if you are using theme:  `.NoActionBar`
set this in your `onCreate()`

```
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

Answer (score 2):

This is very odd. I'm using build tools 25.0.1 and support lib 25.1.0. For me the accepted answer was not necessary, but the way the menu item was defined needs a small change. I need it like so:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<item
    android:id="@+id/search"
    android:title="@string/search_title"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_search_24dp"
    app:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView"
    app:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"/>
```

Where `app:showAsAction` is the key. Lint underlines this as red and tells me:

> Should use `android:showAsAction` when using the appcompat library.

However if I have it set to `android:showAsAction` then the search view simply does not appear. Go figure.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have add AppCompat library to your project. Is your activity was extended "AppCompatActivity"?

And also showAsAction shoud be: `showAsAction="always|collapseActionView"`

Hope this help!

Comment: I'm in a fragment and my MainActivity extends from AppCompactActivity
Before the Update to 24.0.0 it works

Answer (score 0):

None of the answers worked for me. I realized my case was a bit different. I omitted this line inside the fragment's onViewCreated()

```
setHasOptionsMenu(true)
```

Worked for me