# Android Support Library 24.0.0 does not show text in SearchView

Tags: android, searchview, android-appcompat

Here is what my SearchView looks like using [Android Support Library version 23.0.4](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions.html):

[image]

And here is what it looks like using [Support Library 24.0.0](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions.html):

[image]

How can I get my [SearchView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SearchView.html) to properly show text in 24.0.0? This is not a text color issue FYI, I have [adjusted text color of the EditText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321129/is-it-possible-to-change-the-textcolor-on-an-android-searchview) to no avail. You can also see it is missing the "x" button on the right.

**Update**

Here is the XML I am using for my search menu:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/search"
        android:icon="@drawable/nav_icon_search"
        android:title="@string/search"
        app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView" />
</menu>
```

Here is the code I am using in my onCreateOptionsMenu:

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_location_list, menu);
    this.configureSearchView(menu);
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}

private void configureSearchView(Menu menu) {
    MenuItem search = menu.findItem(R.id.search);
    MenuItemCompat.setOnActionExpandListener(search, this);

    this.mSearchView = (SearchView)   
    MenuItemCompat.getActionView(search);
    this.mSearchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
    this.mSearchView.setOnCloseListener(this);
    this.mSearchView.setSubmitButtonEnabled(false);
    this.mSearchView.setIconifiedByDefault(true);

    this.mSearchMenuItem = search;
}
```

Comment: Did you set the text color to white ??

Comment: I set the text color to every possible iteration including white. No avail. It's not just the text color; there is an initial icon that is not visible too (prior to entering text).

Comment: @esilver could you share the xml for your search menu, as well as your onCreateOptionsMenu() method?

Comment: @Dr.Nitpick Shared

Comment: Man, I am confused as to why this is not working. I tried out the code you shared on an app compiled against sdk 24, build tools 24 and support lib 24 and it worked just fine. I did have to coment out the line where you set your activity as the `OnActionExpandListener` but that was it. It may work correctly if you comment it out as well? Are you doing anything in `onMenuItemActionExpand` that would prevent the search view from expanding properly?

Comment: Besides what I said above, I am not sure I can give you any helpful input without seeing your project code, and that seems like a heavy handed approach. I'm sorry mate, if I think of anything else I will let you know.

Comment: Did you tried this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38048481/2498248 ?

Comment: @Alex that solved it! though I used the height android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize" instead.